# Livewire 3 build form component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to create a Form for a livewire component that will handle an offer creation form.

How in the form can I define the product fields that need to be in the array?

Everywhere is to show how to make a form with validation in the first line and how when we just assume the products and contractor will be embedded in arrays?

Contractors will have two arrays with type 0 (invoice data) and 1 shipping data.

I would appreciate in advance a hint and help on how to do this.

```
class DocumentOrderForm extends Form
{
    public ?DocumentOrder $documentOrder = null;

    #[Rule('required')]
    public int $commercial_location_id = 1;
    public int $delivery_method_id = 1;
    public int $payment_method_id = 1;
    public $date_of_issue = now();
    public $completion_date;
    public $expiry_date;

    public array $contractors;
    public array $products;


}
```

I tried to embed the forms in the form but it doesn't work as it should.

```
        $contractors = [
            [
                'type_id' => 0,
                'name' => '',
                'address' => '',
                'code' =>'',
                'city' =>'',
            ],
            [
                'type_id' => 1,
                'name' => '',
                'address' => '',
                'code' =>'',
                'city' =>'',
            ]
        ];
```